# Finding the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ for which this series converges, but not absolutely

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ for which series $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n^b(\ln(n))^c}$$ converges, but not absolutely.

I tried using the Ratio Test $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{a}{1+b/n}\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right)^c$$

What can I do from here?

Edit: Since while calculating limit n tends to infinity The function becomes independent of b and c. So is it right to say that convergence only depends on a in this case?

since n tends to infinity b/n=0
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{a}{1+0}\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right)^c$$

Now using l hospital

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{a}{1}\left(1+\frac{1}{(n)}\right)^c$$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{a}{1}\left(1 \right)^c$$

Pls correct me

Comment: Your latex is malformed so it's hard to tell what your attempt was, but if in the denominator you got $1+\frac{b}{n}$ then that seems to be an incorrect algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Is the ratio test bit meant to be formatted as $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{a}{1+\frac{b}{n}}\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right)^c$?

Comment: @Snaw why i used binomial

Comment: That part was supposed to be $\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^b$ which you can simplify to $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^b$, but it does not simplify to the expression you wrote.

Comment: @Eric I've made the change

Comment: I tried to edit so that $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is easier to read. Please change if I made a mistake. Also, you didn't finish applying the Ratio Test: what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}/a_n$? What can you conclude from that? Note that you can compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}$ by L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: @Taladris i wrote that is edit part after applying l hospital the surprising part is limit is independent of b and c which i want to confirm

Comment: If $a=1$, the convergence depends on the value of $b$ and $c$ (the series is a Bertrand series in that case). Note that your ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is incorrect (I only modified the formatting), as Snaw commented.

Comment: @Taladris pls elaborate

Answer (score 1):

$\bullet\ $  If $a \geq 0$, then the general term of the series is positive, so the series cannot be conditionally convergent.

$\bullet\ $  If $a<-1$, then
$$\left|\frac{a^n}{n^b \ln^c(n)} \right| \longrightarrow +\infty$$

so the series does not converge.

$\bullet\ $  If $-1 < a < 0$, then

$$\left|\frac{a^n}{n^b \ln^c(n)} \right|  = O \left( \left( \frac{|a|+1}{2}\right)^n\right)$$

so by comparison the series converges absolutely.

$\bullet\ $ We are left with the case $a=-1$.

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \bullet$ First subcase : $b > 0$. In that case, the series converges by the alternating series test, and converges absolutely iff ($b> 1$ or $b=1$ and $c>0$) (Bertrand series).

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \bullet$ Second subcase : $b< 0$. In that case the general term does not tend to $0$
so te series diverges.

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \bullet$ Third subcase : $b=0$.

$\quad \quad \quad \quad $$\quad \quad \quad \quad \bullet$ First subsubcase : if $c \leq 0$, the general term does not tend to $0$, so the series diverges.

$\quad \quad \quad \quad $$\quad \quad \quad \quad \bullet$ Second subsubcase : if $c > 0$, then the series converges by the alternating series test, and never converges absolutely.

---

All put together, you get that the possible conditions for the series to be conditionally convergent are

- $a=-1$ and $0 < b < 1$.
- $a=-1$ and $b=1$ and $c\leq 0$.
- $a=-1$ and $b=0$ and $c > 0$.